# Shannon entropy function returns -0.0 instead of 0.0

Tags: python, entropy

My Shannon entropy function for "aaaaa" should return 0.0 but gives me -0.0. How do I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Negative 0 is equal to positive 0 so it doesn't need to be fixed. Also, please don't post images of code. Post the code itself as properly formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `-0.0 == 0.0` is true, what you have is mathematically correct. If you find the output unaesthetic, the fix is simple. Don't multiply by `-1`. Take the absolute value instead:

```
from collections import Counter
import math

def entropy(string):
    counts = Counter(string)
    rel_freq = ((i/len(string)) for i in counts.values())
    return abs(sum(f*math.log2(f) for f in rel_freq))
```

Then `entropy('aaaaa')` evaluates to `0.0`.